# What is the purpose of the brackets {} after a gRPC method definition?

Tags: grpc

In gRPC you can define a method like

```
service HelloService {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
}
```

or

```
service HelloService {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse) {}
}
```

(from http://www.grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html#service-definition).

I've looked through the docs and there doesn't seem to be anything you can put inside the brackets. So, given that I can terminate the definition with `;` what are that brackets for?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec#service_definition says "option", which quickly takes you to the Proto2 language guide.

Comment: Oh super there it is! A formal syntax declaration. Not much flavor in the docs, but good to see the formal definition. Thank you.

Comment: Totally a duplicate. Let's close this. Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not an expert but I will try to explain it

You can add custom options in your rpc definitions

For example if you use [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) that allows you to translate the RESTful API into gRPC

In this snippet I'm requesting the `body` field and the RESTful call will be in `/api/{client}` for example:

```
service Builder {
  rpc Generate(Request) returns (Response) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/api/{Client}"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
}
```

You can see full reference here [cloud.google.com/service-management/reference](https://cloud.google.com/service-management/reference/rpc/google.api#http)

Note: I took the reference link from the grpc-gateway repo

Comment: Hey thanks! I didn't google _too_ long, but I definitely didn't find even one example. Thank you! So no official docs, though, it seems.

Comment: Your welcome. I only have used it for grpc-gateway, should be other use cases.